# dagger2 inject generic interface

Tags: java, dagger-2

I want to inject an object of a generic interface type into another object

```
class InjectionTarget {
    @Inject IGenericType<String, Integer> object; 
}

interface IGenericType<A, B> {
    void foo(A a);
    void bar(B b);
}

class GenericTypeImpl<A, B> implements IGenericType<A, B> {
    List<A> someListA = new ArrayList();
    List<B> someListB = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    public void foo(A a) {
        someListA.add(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void bar(B b) {
        someListB.add(b);
    }
}
    
// dagger component and actual injection skipped for clarity
```

I tried to use a provider method, but it causes compilation error (@Provides methods may not have type parameters)

```
@Module
class Module {
  
  // this doesn't compile
  @Provides
  <A, B> IGenericType<A, B> getGenericType() {
    return new GenericTypeImpl<A, B>();
  }
}
```

So I had to move type parameters from @Provides method to class.
Then, since:

- Modules with type parameters must be abstract
- abstract module cannot have instance @Provides methods (all must be static)
- non-static type variable A and B cannot be referenced from a static context

I cannot use @Provides method anymore (even static one, because of type variables), so I ended up with @Binds using @Inject constructor for implementation

```
@Module
public abstract class TestModule<A, B> {

    @Binds
    abstract IGenericType<A, B> getGenericType(GenericTypeImpl<A, B> object);
}

class GenericTypeImpl<A, B> implements IGenericType<A, B> {
    ...       
    @Inject
    public GenericTypeImpl() {}
    ...
}
```

but this fails too with

> IGenericType<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer> cannot be provided
> without an @Provides-annotated method

So it seems a hopeless case. Is there any way to workaround this ? I prefer to avoid adding provider methods for every single type combination I'll use (I expect there will be many of these) and stay with one generic provider/binds method.

Comment: You only know real type of A and B at runtime ?

Comment: At compile time, look at InjectionTarget - it uses specific types (IGenericType<String, Integer> object)

Comment: I don't think you can do it because. 
Because InjectionTarget  defined generique type not in runtime but a "compileTime" you have define `<String, Integer>` yourself.
But If you put `GenericTypeImpl<A, B>` object in your binds. You will not necessary have a IGenericType<String, Integer>...
So you depency graph can't be resolve